# Pie charts on GIS maps using R

Tags: r

I'm an R user and have been using libraries like `gistools` and `rgdal`. I notice that ArcGIS appears to have features to add pie charts onto the maps themselves. (For example, if I have a map of the US, I can add a pie chart to each state). However, a quick search of `gistools` and `rgdal` documentation does not show any function to add such features.

Is there any easy way to add pie charts onto maps in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options depending on which R package you want to use. The following links should give you some insights into some of the possibilities available.

- Using [mapplots](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapplots) and specifically the `add.pie` function (see this [worked example](http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/) and map below)
- Using the [rworldmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/index.html) package as described [here](http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.ie/2013/04/rg-plot-bar-or-pie-chart-over-world-map.html)
- Using the [plotGoogleMaps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotGoogleMaps/index.html) package - see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014261/pie-charts-in-google-map-using-plotgooglemaps)

[image: Example from http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/]

*(Map Sourced from: http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/)*

Comment: I think there's a typo on the maptools page: floating.pie() is supposed to be used with the plotrix package. Also, maptools doesn't have any functions to add pie charts, at least at the time of writing

Comment: Good answer, but add.pie is a function in mapplots rather than maptools

Answer (score 1):

I might add here: 
add.pie() is a function of [mapplots](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapplots/index.html).

In the documentation of "mapplots" draw.pie() is the recommended function to use

Be careful if you combine the package [RgoogleMaps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/index.html) and "mapplots". The coordinates are scaled as soon as you set a "Zoom" parameter. Here an example of an arbitrary data frame:

```
map1=GetBingMap(center=c(47.619048,-122.35384),zoom=15,apiKey=apiKey, 
                  verbose=1, destfile="Seattle.png") 
PlotOnStaticMap(map1)
```

if you add multiple pie charts on the map, this will only give you a cluster in the middle of your plot! (Note df$values is a matrix containing at least two columns corresponding the size of a slice)

```
library(mapplots)
draw.pie(z=df$values, x=df$lat, y=df$long, radius = 20, col=c(alpha("orange", 0.6), alpha("blue", 0.6)), labels="")
```

Hence you will have to rescale your pie chart coordinates first (use the map and zoom factor as above):

```
xy <- LatLon2XY.centered(map1,df$lat, df$long, zoom = 15)

library(mapplots)
draw.pie(z=df$values, x=xy$newX, y=xy$newY, radius = 20, col=c(alpha("orange", 0.6), alpha("blue", 0.6)), labels="")
```